# Entity Framework, Problem with saving new database entry

Tags: c#, postgresql

I was trying to save my new database entry, but ID want increment.

This are table columns:

[image: Procesor table columns]

[image: ID constraints]

I am using Entity Framework and Windows Forms. After adding my postgresql database it created Procesor class.

```
public partial class Procesor
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Naziv_Procesora { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Godina_Proizvodnje { get; set; }
    public string Naziv_Proizvodaca { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Broj_Jezgri { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Takt_Procesora { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Cijena_Procesora { get; set; }

    public virtual Konfiguracija_Racunala Konfiguracija_Racunala { get; set; }
}
```

}

Afther that I created new class for generating Bindning list and inserting into database

```
class Procesori
    {
        public BindingList<Procesor> DohvatiProcesore()
        {
            BindingList<Procesor> listaProcesora;
            using (RacunalaEntities enteties = new RacunalaEntities())
            {
                listaProcesora = new BindingList<Procesor>(enteties.Procesors.ToList());
            }
            return listaProcesora;
        }

        public void unosProcesora(string naziv, int godina, string proizvodac, decimal cijena, int jezgre, double takt)
        {
            using (RacunalaEntities enteties = new RacunalaEntities())
            {
                Procesor procesor = new Procesor();
                procesor.Naziv_Procesora = naziv;
                procesor.Naziv_Proizvodaca = proizvodac;
                procesor.Godina_Proizvodnje = godina;
                procesor.Broj_Jezgri = jezgre;
                procesor.Takt_Procesora = takt;
                procesor.Cijena_Procesora = cijena;

                enteties.Procesors.Add(procesor);
                enteties.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

Inside my Form I wanted to add new Processor to the database and I couldn't

Code for my Form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        RacunalaEntities context = new RacunalaEntities();
        Procesori procesori = new Procesori();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = procesori.DohvatiProcesore();
            
            

        }       

        private void btnDodajProcesore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string nazivProcesora = txtNazivProcesora.Text;
            int godinaProizvodnje = int.Parse(txtGodinaProizvodnje.Text);
            string nazivProizvodaca = txtNazivProizvodaca.Text;
            decimal cijenaProcesora = decimal.Parse(txtCijenaProcesora.Text);
            int brojJezgri = int.Parse(txtBrojJezgri.Text);
            double taktProcesora = double.Parse(txtTaktProcesora.Text);
            procesori.unosProcesora(nazivProcesora,godinaProizvodnje,nazivProizvodaca,cijenaProcesora,brojJezgri,taktProcesora);
            MessageBox.Show("Podaci su spremljeni");
        }
    }
```

Error code:

> PostgresException: 428C9: cannot insert into column "ID"

Answer (score 0):

Try to decorate Id property with following attribute.

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Comment: Sorry but this didn't fix my problem I still have the same error. Inside my DB I can insert values with no problem and ID will be generated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem, first go into your pgAdmin4 and set column constraint Identity BY DEFAULT like this:

[image: Column constraint Identity]

After that go into Visual Studio and open your .edmx model. Inside defined table in my case it was table "Procesor" column "Id" open properties and set Store Generated Pattern to IDENTITY like this:

[image: IDENTITY]

Now everything work fine, my Id is autoincremented :D I was using Database first approach.

Answer (score 0):

While @Dominik's answer solve the issue, it seemed to be hectic as my db going to be huge. I needed a one-time solution to fix this forever. I checked what's there in the `EntityFramework6.npgsql` and figured out an issue with `PgTableColumns`'s `DefiningQuery` (found in `Resources\NpgsqlSchema.ssdl`), it wasn't identifying the `is_identity` property correctly. So, I decided to change it and used that dll instead of Nuget's

```
    select
    cast(a.attrelid as varchar) || '.' || cast (a.attnum as varchar) as id,
    cast(c.oid as varchar) as table_id,
    a.attname as name,
    a.attnum as ordinal,
    not a.attnotnull as is_nullable,
    t.typname as type_name,
    case
      when t.typname in ('bpchar', 'varchar') and a.atttypmod != -1 then a.atttypmod - 4
      when t.typname in ('bit', 'varbit') and a.atttypmod != -1 then a.atttypmod
      else null
    end as max_length,
    case
      when t.typname = 'numeric' and a.atttypmod != -1 then ((a.atttypmod - 4) >> 16) &amp; 65535
      else null
    end as precision,
    case
      when t.typname in ('time', 'timestamp', 'timestamptz') and a.atttypmod != -1 then a.atttypmod
      when t.typname = 'interval' and a.atttypmod &amp; 65535 != 65535 then a.atttypmod &amp; 65535
      else null
    end as datetime_precision,
    case
      when t.typname = 'numeric' and a.atttypmod != -1 then (a.atttypmod - 4) &amp; 65535
      else null
      end as scale,
      case
      when t.typlen = -1 and t.typelem != 0 then true
      else false
      end as is_multiset,
      null as collation_catalog_name,
      null as collation_schema_name,
      null as collation_name,
      null as char_set_catalog_name,
      null as char_set_schema_name,
      null as char_set_name,
      case when (select is_identity from information_schema.columns k where nspname=k.table_schema and
      a.attname=k.column_name  and c.relname= k.table_name) ='YES' then true else false end is_identity,
      false as is_generated,
      -- default value column
      pg_get_expr(ad.adbin, ad.adrelid) as default_value
      from pg_attribute a
      join pg_class c
      on a.attrelid = c.oid
      join pg_namespace n
      on c.relnamespace = n.oid
      join pg_type t
      on a.atttypid = t.oid
      left join pg_attrdef ad
      on a.attrelid = ad.adrelid and a.attnum = ad.adnum
      where t.typtype = 'b' and c.relkind = 'r' and a.attnum >= 0 and c.relnamespace in
      (select oid from pg_namespace where nspname not in ('pg_catalog','information_schema','pg_toast'))
```